# Can I make TeX completely free-form?

Tags: tex-core

I'm bothered about the language format of TeX.

I mean I want to know why the `CR` is converted into a space and `%` must be at the end of a line to avoid the matter. To make matters worse, a blank line means the end of a paragraph.

I know these functions are useful in most cases. But, in macros or something like that, they bother me; I guess many package writers too.

My questions are "Can I nullify these functions using some macros (such as `\catcode`)?" and "Can I make TeX completely free-form?"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'completely free-form'.

Comment: Excuse me for my less explanation. I mean free-form computer language.

Comment: Could you give a link to something explaining what that is? I'm not a CS person, so I've no idea what a 'free-form computer language' means (or what it would mean specifically for TeX). When I looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-form_language, the description seemed to be about indentation, which TeX already ignores.

Comment: TeX's ability to change `\catcode`'s might be tempting and powerful. However, it hurts *much* more than it seems. In general, a good practice is to avoid it whenever you can and limit its application to the smallest possible scope and to the most specialized use-cases (like verbatim printing). It almost always breaks other packages.

Comment: Mr.Wright, I read your link. But it also says "frequently ends of lines are insignificant," in the second line. Isn't it about line-breaks? In fact, I am a Japanese and Japanese Wikipedia (http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%88_%28%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%29) says "空白や改行文字," which means spaces and line-breaks. So, now I don't know which is right. If I made some mistakes, I apologize you all.

Comment: @YotaToyama Well yes-and-no. With standard settings, breaking a line in TeX input is equivalent to a space, so is 'insignificant'. TeX does however have the blank line (two newlines in a row) to `\par` conversion. In my answer, I've turned that off but at the cost you need an explicit `\par` for each new paragraph. As I said, TeX (and derivatives) is focussed on typesetting so that is what the standard settings are for.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

TeX is a typesetting system, and so the standard set up is biased toward document 'text': the normal conventions work well for this at the cost of slightly more work for 'programming'. (Other parts of TeX's programming model are more 'work' in this regard, but that is a separate issue.)

It certainly is possible to modify the standard behaviour. For example, in the `expl3` language used for LaTeX3 programming (a 'work in progress'), the set up is based on something similar to

```
\catcode`\^^I = 9 %
\catcode`\  = 9 %
\catcode`\^^M = 10 %
\endlinechar = `\  %
\relax
Hello world

more text
\bye
```

which you could modify to simply

```
\catcode`\^^M = 10 %
\endlinechar = `\ %
\relax
Hello world

more text
\bye
```

if you only want the change in end-of-line behaviour. Note that this then requires you to explicitly add in paragraphs using `\par`.